# iTunes connect giving access to developers

Tags: ios, itunes, app-store-connect

I've registered as a iOS company developer. And I've been able to give access to my developer (from Manage Users/iTunes Connect User/Technical role, I've even tried giving Admin role) but he does not seem to be able to register bundle identifier (which is required to 'Add New App').
I can register the bundle identifier myself, but the app is being developed remotely and I want the developer to be able to manage apps himself.

1. Do the developers also have to join/pay for iOS developer program separately?
2. Is there anything I'm missing while giving the user with roles (again I've tried giving admin, technilcal roles) ?
3. How long does it take to come changes in effect?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each developer must have his own developer account and must be in your team. if they dont have an account, they can sign for free, they dont need a paid account. then you can invite them to your team and you can assign the rights.

Comment: they have also access to the company developer account or only to tunes connect? remember that first the app id must be created in the provisioning portal before you can create in tunes connect

Comment: I created company id then invited developer using his email address. He's got access to iTunes connect.